# Partial black screen in Virtualbox Kali Linux 2021.2 guest machine

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, kali-linux

I installed the lastest edition of Kali Linux 2021.2 as a VM in Virtualbox. I followed the official instructions. It was working fine for the first 2 days. Suddenly one day, the GUI started displaying only parts of it and the rest was a black screen.

[image: GUI after logging in is problematic]

The display during the boot process is fine. Even the login screen and the virtual consoles are fine. After I login, the display looks normal for 2 to 3 seconds, and goes back to this.

I have restarted the `virtualbox-guest-utils`, `lightdm.service`, `display-manager.service` and the machine itself multiple times. I reinstalled `virtualbox-guest-x11` and `virtualbox-guest-utils` packages. There aren't any logs written to the machine log files after I boot the machine. Other linux machines on my PC are not facing this issue. I couldn't find anything in Kali bug tracker too. Oh, and the video recording feature of virtualbox is not working. It is recording only a part of the visible screen and the rest is black.

Personally, I think this is a problem in the guest itself and not Virtualbox. Might have messed up some configuration. But I'm unable to fix this issue. What do I do?

[image: Login screen has no issues]

Comment: Try logging in to a terminal screen using Ctrl-Alt-F1 and then run sudo apt autoremove followed by sudo apt update followed by sudo apt upgrade. Restart when done and see if the regular start is now normal.

Comment: I tried this again. Did not work :(

Comment: I don't know for sure (I am running Kali 2021.2 here). Try:  sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove
and see if that works. Otherwise try making a new virtual machine.